# How do i delete multiple selected Files only from a s3 bucket which has S3 url?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, scripting

i have a excel sheet which contains s3 file name & s3 static url , i want to delete these objects at once . Total number of files are 1000+ .So any script i can use to delete these files will be helpful .

Comment: This community is created to help you with programming questions, not to write code for you from scratch. What have you tried so far? What problems are you encountering? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Do the files exist in an Amazon S3 bucket that you have permission to access?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to delete the files, if you have AWS credentials with permission to delete the objects.

I would recommend that you add another column to the spreadsheet that inserts the file details into formula that would generate this:

```
aws s3 rm s3://BUCKET-NAME/path/file.txt
```

You could then copy the command from Excel and paste it into the command line to tell the AWS CLI to delete the file. Test it on a few first, to make sure it works.

Then, use Fill Down and copy/paste all the commands into the command line.